# How to remove pushed commits from me and someone else on github?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

[image: In this picture] you can see the last commits. The last two are from me and the 3 after that are from someone else. These should be deleted and the branch should be set to the previous state of the commit "menu scene toegevoegd". How can i do this? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not recommended, since this will break local copies on other developpers machine, but it is possible.

First, reset your local branch to the desired commit

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard 21fd53a
```

Then, push this on remote server (GitHub) using `--force` modifier to explicitely indicate that you want to force this destructive action

```
git push --force origin develop
```